# count frequency of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

someone could help me please, I'm new to python.

I want to count the number of occurrences for each element in a row.

For example, for column A and row 0 I would like to get the following result: the number of times 10 appears = 1, and 20 = 2.

for column A and row 2, the desired result is: 15 = 2 and 10 = 1.
I would like to do this for all rows in a given column:

My dataframe is like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

A=[['10','20','20'],['20','10','10'],['15','10','15'],'12']
B=[['30','20','30'],'10',['5','30','30'],'40']
C=[['0','0'],'30','5','8']

df=pd.DataFrame({
                "A":A,
                "B":B,
                "C":C})
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0xY6.png

Comment: Do you need to use pandas? An easier approach might be using a [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: What did you try so far and where are you stuck at the moment? Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: I tried this, but it not given me a result what I want to obtain
```python 
import collections
collections.Counter(df)
```
This is result that give me: 
Counter({'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}) 

When I try :
 ```python
collections.Counter(df['A'])
``` 
It given me an error: 
```python
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

```
import collections

def lst_count(lst):
    lst_counter = []
    for val in lst:
        if type(val) == type([]):
            lst_counter.append(list((collections.Counter(val).items())))
        else:
            lst_counter.append(list(collections.Counter([val]).items()))
    print (lst_counter)
lst_count(A)
```

Output will be

[[('10', 1), ('20', 2)], [('20', 1), ('10', 2)], [('15', 2), ('10', 1)], [('12', 1)]]

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

A=[['10','20','20'],['20','10','10'],['15','10','15'],'12']
B=[['30','20','30'],'10',['5','30','30'],'40']
C=[['0','0'],'30','5','8']

df=pd.DataFrame({
                "A":A,
                "B":B,
                "C":C}) 

# Add the following lines to your file

# fetching the column headings 
col_names = [col for col in df.columns]

# using the following for loops to iterate through each cell of the dataframe
for item in col_names:
  for index in range(len(df)):
    
    # following prints the current cell address
    print( "For cell (" + item + "," + str(index) + ") :" )

    # for fetching each unique element of the cell of dataframe
    for set_item in set(df[item][index]):

      print("Count of " + str(set_item)+ " -> " + str( df[item][index].count(set_item)), end='    ' )
    print()
```

As the dataframe you are working with is a small one, we can afford having three for loops. Otherwise, thought can be given for better approach.